# Material Library VX Textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, add-on

im trying to set up my material library with Material Library VX addon.
It works fine but when i apply a material in a new scene it packs the textures in to
the blendfile. Is there a way that the textures are not packed, so i dont need to
click “Use file in original location” every time?